# webview URL not updating via FCM when Splash Screen is added

Tags: java, android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=frfTJDacxIc) to make a simple webview app where the url of the webview can be updated from a key and a value from a Firebase Notification, the webview load a static url, but also load a new url specified in the value of the FCM notification

The `onNewIntent(getIntent());` gets the intent from `mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver` that contains key: `webURL` and the value: `https://www.newurl.com/` stored in `STR_KEY`.

Everything works fine, the url updates perfectly when the app is in the background and foreground... until i add a Splash Screen in the app, in this case, when the app is in the background and the FCM notification arrives, the url of the webview doesn't update, but it does when it's in the foreground.

My best guess is that the `Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);` is lost because the Splash Screen loads first instead of the Main activity, but I'm a noob and this is beyond the 3 neurons that I have.

This is my manifest:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".Splash">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"></activity>

    <service android:name=".MyService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
</application>
```

My FCM Service:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

public class MyService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    public static final String STR_KEY = "webURL";
    public static final String STR_PUSH = "pushNotification";
    public static final String STR_MESSAGE = "message";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        handleMessage(remoteMessage.getData().get(STR_KEY));
    }

    private void handleMessage(String message) {
        Intent pushNotification = new Intent(STR_PUSH);
        pushNotification.putExtra(STR_MESSAGE, message);

    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNewToken(String token) {
        super.onNewToken(token);
        sendRegistrationToServer(token);
    }

    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
        Log.d("new Token", token);
    }
}
```

My MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView webView;

    private BroadcastReceiver mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver;

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.OFF);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Android Mozilla/5.0 
        AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30");
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
        webView.getSettings().supportZoom();
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl("https://www.mywebsite.com/");

        mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                if (intent.getAction().equals(STR_PUSH)) {
                    String message = intent.getStringExtra(STR_MESSAGE);
                    showNotification("New URL", message);
                }
            }
        };

        onNewIntent(getIntent());

    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
            webView.loadUrl(intent.getStringExtra(STR_KEY));
    }

    private void showNotification(String title, String message) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(STR_KEY, message);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), 0, 
                intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(getBaseContext());
        builder.setAutoCancel(true)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
        getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            String channelId = getString(R.string.normal_channel_id);
            String channelName = getString(R.string.normal_channel_name);
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, 
        channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        channel.enableVibration(true);
        channel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 200, 50});
        if (notificationManager != null) {
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        builder.setChannelId(channelId);
    }

    if (notificationManager !=null) {
        notificationManager.notify("", 0, builder.build());
    }
}

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver
        (mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver);
        super.onPause();
}

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver
        (mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("registrationComplete"));
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver
        (mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(STR_PUSH));
    }
}
```

And my Splash Screen:

```
public class Splash extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
        int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 4000;
        new Handler().postDelayed(() -> {
            Intent homeIntent = new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(homeIntent);
            finish();
        }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should implement your splash screen without using a layout file, since there is a delay in launching your second activity from a dedicated splash screen activity.

This article may be of help- [creating splashscreen the right way](https://android.jlelse.eu/right-way-to-create-splash-screen-on-android-e7f1709ba154)

This way, the splash screen will only show if the app is in loading state. Therefore it should prevent your problem, even when the app is running in background.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it doesn't fixed my problem... in fact, that splash screen showed me a blank screen in a couple of times instead of the logo that I specified.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView webView;
    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    private BroadcastReceiver mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("https://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_note20-10338.php");
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    request.grant(request.getResources());
                }
//                super.onPermissionRequest(request);
            }
        });
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                if (dialog.isShowing())
                    dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                if (intent.getAction().equals(Config.STR_PUSH)) {
                    String message = intent.getStringExtra(Config.STR_MESSAGE);
                    showNotification("this is a notification", message);
                }
            }
        };

        onNewIntent(getIntent());

    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingSuperCall")
    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

        if (intent.getStringExtra(Config.STR_KEY) != null) {
            dialog.show();
            dialog.setMessage("Please wait loading");
            webView.loadUrl(intent.getStringExtra(Config.STR_KEY));
        }
    }

    private void showNotification(String title, String message) {
//        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
//        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
//        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        intent.putExtra(Config.STR_KEY, message);
//        intent.setFlags(intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        intent.setFlags(intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
//        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(),0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

//        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getBaseContext());
        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            builder.setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(message)
                    .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                    .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                    .setVibrate(new long[]{100, 200, 200, 50})
                    .setColor(Color.rgb(247, 133, 39))
                    .setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                    .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));
        }

//        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            String channelId = "ChannelID";
            String channelName = "ChannelName";
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            channel.enableLights(true);
            channel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
            channel.enableVibration(true);
            channel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
            channel.setShowBadge(true);
            channel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 200, 50});
            if (notificationManager != null) {
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
            }
            builder.setChannelId(channelId);
        }

        if (notificationManager != null) {
            notificationManager.notify("", 0, builder.build());
        }

//        notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver);
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("registrationComplete"));
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(Config.STR_PUSH));

    }

}
```

Comment: Please consider adding explanation to your code.